# SQL Server name using port number

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server express 2014. I used the below connection string as server name in SQL Express. but it failed.

**[my servername],1433\SQLEXPRESS**

In sql server 2012, I can connect the connection string in the format of **[my servername],1433**

Could you please anyone suggest how do I specify a port number in a connection string for SQL Express server?

Comment: instance name,port number should be correct

Answer (score 10):

First of all, if you did not change the port manually, `SQLEXPRESS` is NOT listening on `1433` that is reserved for default instance, it uses `dynamic` port that you can find in Configuration Manager or in SQL Server error log.
Here you can see both methods with pictures: [Identify SQL Server TCP IP port being used](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2495/identify-sql-server-tcp-ip-port-being-used/).

Second, there is no need to specify instance name + port, in fact if you do it, instance name is effectively ignored, so when you use

```
[my servername]\SQLEXPRESS,1433
```

you'll try to connect to

```
[my servername],1433
```

That is because to connect to server you need to know it's address and port, so or you use

```
myServer,port
```

or you use

```
myServer\instanceName
```

In the first case the underlying network library has all information it needs to connect(IP + port). In the second case SQL Server Browser need to be started.
It's SQL Server Browser that will comunicate instance `port` given `instance name`.

When your connection string contains both instance name and port, only port is used and instance name is ignored, so if you use a wrong port, even with correct instance name you cannot connect.

Comment: This helped me get connected from SQL Management Studio, which also accepts the "[my servername]\SQLEXPRESS,1433" format for the "Server Name" box on the "Connect to Server" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

put the port after the instance name, like:

```
[my servername]\SQLEXPRESS,1433
```

Have in mind that if SQL Express is the only SQL server in this PC you can also use:

```
[my servername],1433 or [serverIP],1433
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to use connection string like below. [my servername]:[port number]

Comment: @apomene >>>Have in mind that if SQL Express is the only SQL server in this PC you can also use:

[my servername],1433 or [serverIP],1433<<< If the port of Express is not 1433, be it the only server or not, you cannot connect to it using wrong port number

Comment: @sepupic, using a wrong port on a connection string will always cause problem, no matter if there is only one instance or not. I am not sure what is the point of your comment

Comment: @apomene I don't understand YOUR point. What changes if the server is the only instance on that pc or not? It changes absolutely nothing

Comment: @sepupic you can omit '\SQLEXPRESS" part

Comment: Maybe you wanted to say that if the instance is the DEFAULT instance you can connect to it using only pc_name? Without precising a port, because the default instance uses 1433 by default?

Comment: @apomene  >>>you can omit '\SQLEXPRESS" part <<< If you use PORT in the connection string, you ALWAYS can omit InstanceName (\SQLEXPRESS)

Comment: Moreover, if you use a port, you SHOULD omit instance name, as it will not be used anyway