# How to Connect to Localhost SQL Server When Instance is Not Default

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm setting up a localhost SQL Server and gave a custom instance name called "HOMESERVER"
When I tried to connect to it via SSMS I typed the instance name, ., and nothing connects.
If I use the default name the SQL Server provides, I can connect by using "."

I'm probably missing something on the server name (machine name?).

Are you guys able to guide me?

Cheers

Comment: localhost\HOMESERVER

Comment: More generally, you always connect to some instance with the name `{computername},{port}\{instancename}`.

Comment: Is it not ```{computername}\{instancename},{port}```?

Comment: @Otter Your comment make me doubt myself, so I have to correct. Yes, it's the way you put. But! If you put both port and instance name, the instance name is effectively ignored and the port takes precedence (the instance name is just used as input to the SQL Browser service, which gives the port). Souce: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46824012/2557263

Comment: @Alejandro, when a port number is specified, the instance name is ignored.

Comment: Thank you @Sergey. That did it.